# Authentication to Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: windows-8

I'm looking for ways to authenticate into my Metro App by Kerberos or third party systems like LDAP.
Is there a way to do this?
To give an overview of what my App requires is,
My Windows 8 system is registered with an LDAP. Hence, an LDAP user is able to log into the system.
But now I want that particular user to not have any challenge thrown while accessing my Metro App. Rest any user who isn't authorized should be thrown the challenge. This is possible via Kerberos on Websites and Share point servers but I don't know how to use this feature in my Metro App.